# .htaccess RewriteRule for subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have site e.g. `123.123.123.123/subdirectory/` and I would like to rewrite
`123.123.123.123/subdirectory/page/123`
to
`123.123.123.123/subdirectory/page.php?id=123`.

I've created .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdirectory
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ page.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

but it doesn't work (rewriting in on).

Comment: @anubhava Yes, it is in /subdirectory/.

Comment: @anubhava I'm getting 404 error.

Comment: @anubhava Ok, now I'm getting 500. What's next?

Comment: Try turning off the multiviews

Comment: @anubhava The problem was in `page.php` name. I've changed name of this file and it works. It seems like there was something wrong with `/page/` and `page.php` together in RewriteRule. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Use this rule and it will work.

```
RewriteRule ^123\.123\.123\.123/subdirectory/page/123$ /123.123.123.123/subdirectory/page.php?id=123&%{QUERY_STRING}
```